# Angular Material: Overlay over a Material Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an opened dialog. I want to drop on the dialog a file. The drag'ndrop events are clear. I want to overlay the dialog with a component which indicated it can be dropped here. I thought I use an `Overlay` to indicate this:

```
constructor(private overlay: Overlay,   ) {}

showOverlay() {
        const overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
            positionStrategy: this.overlay.position().global().centerHorizontally().centerVertically(),
            hasBackdrop: true,
        });
        overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(DropMessageComponent));
        setTimeout(() => {
            overlayRef.detach();
        }, 5000);
    }
```

My problem is that the `overlay` covers the whole screen. I want to cover it ONLY the component which I use the `overlay`. I found some samples but none are working with Angular 14 Material (e.g. because the constructor of the `Overlay` has been changed).

Any hints?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as prev comment

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that I need to set

```
hasBackdrop:false
```

(or omit it since its the default value). I needed to set `DropMessageComponent` the `width` and `height` to 100%. With this setting it covers part where I want to include it into the component.

At the very end I was surprised that the `hasBackdrop:false` was the easiest solution.